How to use localStorage to store data
I'm currently trying to learn how to use localStorage. I find myself in a loop while trying to add/update an array of users.
Here's the code:
const users = [
    {name: 'john', age: 25,},
    {name: 'jane', age: 25},
    {name: 'bob', age: 8}
]


const newUserInput = document.querySelector('#newuser');
const newAgeInput = document.querySelector('#newage');
const addUserBtn = document.querySelector("#addnewuser");

addUserBtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();

   
    users.push(createUser(newUserInput.value, parseInt(newAgeInput.value)));
    localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
   
})

const createUser = (name, age) => {
    return {
        "name": name,
        "age": age
    };
    

}


So when i createUser for the first time, it worked and the updated users get stored into localStorage. But when i did it the second time, instead of adding another user, it only updates the first user that i added. Also, even if this works like I wanted to, I'm thinking I might run into a similar problem when I refresh the page, because now I'm redefining users with the original 3 members at the start again.
Any inputs would be very appreciated.

You need to get the existing items from local storage instead of re-creating users all over again.

Hi thank you so much for your answer! I thought so too but I didn't know how to give the users variable existing users and get it to retrieve from localStorage at the same time.. Now i know


Get existing items from local storage with the 'users' key. If it does not exist, then use the array of user objects that you made.
let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [
    {name: 'john', age: 25},
    {name: 'jane', age: 25},
    {name: 'bob', age: 8}
];


Use let instead of const for users, this makes it mutable or modifiable rather than making it immutable or not modifiable.


Hope these two steps help.
TLDR: Change your const users into the code in step 1

Hi, thank you so much for your answer! it worked!

Your welcome! @Andrey Make sure to put this as Answer, so that others having similar issues could try the solution!

the users array is reinitialized with the original three members, and any previously added users stored in localStorage are ignored
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [
       { name: 'john', age: 25 },
       { name: 'jane', age: 25 },
       { name: 'bob', age: 8 }
     ];

   const newUserInput = document.querySelector('#newuser');
   const newAgeInput = document.querySelector('#newage');
   const addUserBtn = document.querySelector("#addnewuser");

   addUserBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const newUser = createUser(newUserInput.value, parseInt(newAgeInput.value));
    users.push(newUser);
      localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));

      //-->Optionally, clear input fields after adding a user
     newUserInput.value = '';
     newAgeInput.value = '';
  });

  const createUser = (name, age) => {
      return {
         name: name,
         age: age
      };
   };
});


thank you so much for your answer! I'm learning so much from this..

// Load users from localStorage or use default array
let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [
    {name: 'john', age: 25},
    {name: 'jane', age: 25},
    {name: 'bob', age: 8}
];

// Function to create a new user object
const createUser = (name, age) => ({ name, age });

// Get DOM elements
const newUserInput = document.querySelector('#newuser');
const newAgeInput = document.querySelector('#newage');
const addUserBtn = document.querySelector("#addnewuser");

// Add event listener for the add user button
addUserBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

// Create and add new user
users.push(createUser(newUserInput.value, parseInt(newAgeInput.value)));

// Save updated users array to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));

// Clear input fields
newUserInput.value = '';
newAgeInput.value = '';
});


hi thank you so much for the answer! I didn't know I could use || operator on a variable.. Does this mean JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) takes priority over [
{name: 'john', age: 25},
{name: 'jane', age: 25},
{name: 'bob', age: 8}
]; ?

Hi. Yes, so when you use || then JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) will take first priority and the 2nd array of objects is used if the first condition returns null.
